# Tensorflow Keras error "no algorithm found!"

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am currently following the book Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, but I keep coming across these errors. When I run the following code:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="nadam", metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
y_pred = model.predict(X_new)
```

I get this error

> NotFoundError:  No algorithm worked!
> [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at :2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2275]

Function call stack:
train_function

I then pulled these two things from stack overflow, which seemed to "fix" the problem

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = "2"

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

However then this message clogs my terminal:

> 2021-04-10 18:20:01.643838: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:235] Your CUDA software stack is old. We fallback to the NVIDIA driver for some compilation. Update your CUDA version to get the best performance. The ptxas error was: ptxas fatal   : Value 'sm_86' is not defined for option 'gpu-name'

I am running cuda 11.2, and I have driver version 460.39. My card is a 3080.
Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: you might think you are running cuda 11.2 but your TF/Keras is using some other version of CUDA.  Also note that the message you are asking about is a warning.

Comment: Check the environment variables - they might be pointing to an older installation. If you tried to upgrade the cuda stack, you might find that there are multiple older entries there (at least that was what happened to me)